# What are the refresh characteristics of the Google Spreadsheet Import functions?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, importxml, importhtml, importdata

The imported data is not always up to date with the source pages when I load the spreadsheet. When this happens, F5 refresh does not help. Nor does Ctl-F5. Apparently there is some kind of caching going on.

I'm thinking that they may be limiting the URL fetches when I try to refresh too often - like when I'm actively modifying my spreadsheet.

Doc reference: http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75507

Comment: Did you try the hack Chris?

Answer (score 7):

As per this [Google Docs Forum thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=061199840171feea&hl=en), *the data should refresh about every hour*

In that thread, a poster suggests appending a random querystring to the URL you wish to scrape from -

> I used a simple workaround of
>   appending a parameter which updates
>   every minute.
>
> Function call is:
>   =ImportHtml("http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/standings/index.html?"&H81;"table";4)
>
> Formula in H81 is: =Minute(Now())
>
> This does the trick for me.

Comment: Really good one :)

Comment: Interesting they say hourly. I seem to get instantaneous data with every page load. That is until it balks. Perhaps the 1 hour delay kicks in. But what is the rhyme or reason to the lock-down. I'll try your hack when that happens. Thanks.

Comment: At this time, the proposed formula returns "Error: This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()"

Answer (score 7):

#Short answer

You are right, the import functions updates their result at certain intervals.

#Explanation
From [Change a spreadsheet's locale, time zone, recalculation, and language](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en), a help article from the official documentation,

> Note: External data functions recalculate at the following intervals:
>
> - ImportRange: 30 minutes
> - ImportHtml, ImportFeed, ImportData, ImportXml: 1 hour
> - GoogleFinance: 2 minutes

It's worth to say that formulas are recalculated when they their arguments changes, so we could use this to force a refresh of the imported data.

### Workaround

One way to force the recalculation of formulas with import functions is to concatenate to the URL a deterministic but innocuous parameter.

###Example

In the following example, "#rev="&A2 is added to the original URL

A1: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitationally_rounded_objects_of_the_Solar_System`
A2: `1`
A3: `4`
A4: `=IMPORTHTML(A1&"#rev="&A2,"table",A3)`

Every time that any of the values or A1, A2, or A3 changes, the formula will be recalculated. We could change the value of A2 to "force" a refresh of the table 4 from the URL in A1.

### Custom time refresh interval for import functions

To have a custom refresh interval for import functions, use a time-driven trigger script to update the deterministic but innocuous URL parameter.

```
/**
 *
 * Updates at the interval set in the time driven trigger configuration
 * a cell value to be used as a deterministic bu unnicouus URL parameter 
 *
 */
function forceRefresh() {
  //Cell addrees of the deterministic but unnicouos URL parameter
  var reference = 'Sheet1!A2';   
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
  rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
}
```

#References

- [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start)
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Where do we set the custom time in the script?

Comment: @thentangler As the answer says, "...use a time-driven trigger script..." -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that does not rely on link modification:

> =if(Minute(Now())=Minute(Now()),ImportHtml("http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/standings/index.html?";"table";4),"")

Since `Minute(Now())=Minute(Now())` is always true, the if will always return the ImportHtml

Comment: How do you know that data retrieved is the last version instead of a cached version?

Answer (score -1):

Click File > Spreadsheet Setting... and check both sheets are in the same Locale and if responses are coming from Jotforms, set the same Locale there too.

Answer (score -2):

### Force recalculation of importrange by reinstating the cell formula

***Required:***

Imported Data - Your target where everything will be copied to.

Imported Data Config - Has the following fields:

```
+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                      A                      |               B                |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Import Data from Spreadsheet with the key:  | key                            |
| Import Data from Spreadsheet between range: | A:AA                           |
| Imported Data select columns:               | SELECT *                       |
| Imported Data criteria:                     | WHERE Col2 contains 'XYZ' |
| Imported Data should by ordered by column:  | ORDER BY Col2                  |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

***Script:***

```
function onOpen() {
try {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
}
catch(err)
{
Browser.msgBox(err);
}

var configsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Imported Data Config");

var configkey = configsheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
var configrange = configsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
var configselect = configsheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
var configwhere = configsheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
var configorderby = configsheet.getRange("B5").getValue();

var importedsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Imported Data");
importedsheet.getRange("A1").setValue('=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("' + configkey + '","' + configrange + '"),"' + configselect + ' ' + configwhere + ' ' + configorderby + '")');

SpreadsheetApp.flush();

// Solution of sourcecode is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631584/how-can-i-force-a-recalculation-of-cell-using-importrange-function-in-a-google-s
// OnOpen Trigger: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers
// Active Spreadsheet solution: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/XIY0WNX0uL8

Browser.msgBox("Sync Complete!");
}
```

This allows you to change your formula without editing the script, and make it easier to transfer the script across various sheets.

**NOTE: This is no longer required in the New Google Sheets released in May 2014.**

Comment: Thanks for posting. You seem to be adding it to quite a few question here on SE. Does it actually help the OP?

Answer (score -3):

The minute now does work very well (and you can just include that within the formula rather than referencing a cell).

However, with some URLs it does not work and appears to change the link itself and may reference another sheet.

I'm not going to be specific, but a link ending for example in:

```
.....ranking?ranking=xp_total&table=0"&Minute(Now()),"table",4)
```

will mess up the link itself. Not a full proof solution but still work for probably 90% of the links people use.

Comment: At this time, Google Sheets doesn't allow the use of non-deterministic functions on import functions.