# How can I decrease IMPORTXML refresh interval to 10 mins?

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I have a couple of `IMPORTXML`’s fetching the prices for products, and I want the sheet to update the prices every 10 mins. I tried `now()` and a functions script but to no avail. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the refresh characteristics of the Google Spreadsheet Import functions?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/what-are-the-refresh-characteristics-of-the-google-spreadsheet-import-functions)

Comment: Check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872967/periodically-refresh-importxml-spreadsheet-function